# Spark export to csv no longer works

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, export-to-csv, crc

I'm using Spark 2.2.0 and I have the following DF:

```
testSchema = t.StructType(
    [t.StructField('a', t.FloatType(), True),
     t.StructField('b', t.FloatType(), True),
     t.StructField('c', t.FloatType(), True),
     t.StructField('d', t.FloatType(), True),
     t.StructField('e', t.FloatType(), True)]
)

test_df = (
    sqlc
    .createDataFrame([(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                      (2.0, 0.0, -1.0, -3.0, 1.0),
                      (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -2.0)],
                     schema = testSchema)
)

test_df.show()

+---+---+----+----+----+
|  a|  b|   c|   d|   e|
+---+---+----+----+----+
|1.0|2.0| 3.0| 0.0| 0.0|
|2.0|0.0|-1.0|-3.0| 1.0|
|0.0|1.0| 0.0| 0.0|-2.0|
+---+---+----+----+----+
```

I would like to export it into a csv file. The following piece of code has always worked fine:

```
(
    test_df
    .repartition(1)
    .write
    .format('csv')
    .options(header=True, delimiter=';')
    .save('/opt/hitl/test.csv')
)
```

...until now. Now it suddenly seems to no longer work.

What I obtained before was a folder named `test.csv` inside which there is a folder named `_temporary`, then a folder named `0` containing two further folders: `_temporary` again (empty) and `task_20171124154417_1077_m_000000` (everytime a different code). The latter contains my csv file named something like `part-00000-01bc3cc4-988f-4f2f-9edd-89e0db3d6f94-c000.csv` together with a crc file `.part-00000-01bc3cc4-988f-4f2f-9edd-89e0db3d6f94-c000.csv.crc`.

What I now obtain is a folder named `test.csv` again, but inside this folder I have just two files: a crc file named `._SUCCESS.crc` and a `_SUCCESS` file without extension. Nothing else.

I tried to modify the export code above by removing the repartition, then the delimiter, I tried to use the `test_df.write.csv()` command, I tried to change the column type to double or string, but none of these worked: the output is always the same.

Any suggestion?
Thank you very much.

Comment: That might be a permission issue. Do your Spark workers have permission on your output folders ?

Comment: @Jaco I checked the permissions, they seem right to me. Would this be a permission issue, I should not even get the folder with the _SUCCESS files, should I?

Comment: The success file is written by the driver that does have the right permissions. Even previously you had permission issues, as there shouldn't be a `_temporary` folder after a successful run. It seems your Spark workers do not have the same permissions as your driver

Comment: Can you check if your RDD is empty?

Comment: @SudevAmbadi I'm using a DF, not a RDD. By the way I already did this, the DF contains all the data I expect it must contain. I updated the question by showing the content of the DF.

Comment: @Jaco I'm looking further at the permissions, you may be right. I'll let you know asap. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: it was simpler than I thought. The export was working, but the exported csv files were located in a different folder than I expected. For some reason the export procedure now creates two folders at two different locations: one which contains the csv file, the other one which contains the `_SUCCESS` files only.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), you can convert Spark dataframe using `.toPandas()` native method:

```
pdf = test_df.toPandas()
pdf.to_csv('/opt/hitl/test.csv')
```

It could be useful for you.

Comment: IMHO this provide an answer if I understood the question, it was not meant to be a critique, I think it could be a practical way to export results from spark dataset to csv, but under specific circunstances.